# can we limit the Azure region/location of deployment in ARM createUIdefinition.json?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Is it possible to allow a deployment of ARM template in only selected regions/locations of Azure. If so how we can achieve it in createUIdefinition.json ARM template?

Comment: If the answer is helpful you can accept it. Or for more help please let me know.

Comment: I have the exact same question. I 20 different resource types in my ARM template and if they pick certain regions it fails. I want to ONLY show the Regions where I know it can be installed - did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-resource-manager/managed-applications/create-uidefinition-overview.md

> For location, specify the properties for the location control you wish
> to override. Any properties not overridden are set to their default
> values. resourceTypes accepts an array of strings containing fully
> qualified resource type names. The location options are restricted to
> only regions that support the resource types. allowedValues accepts an
> array of region strings. Only those regions appear in the
> dropdown. You can set both allowedValues and resourceTypes. The result
> is the intersection of both lists. Lastly, the visible property can be
> used to conditionally or completely disable the location dropdown.

I tested this and it works:

```
 "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/0.1.2-preview/CreateUIDefinition.MultiVm.json#",
  "handler": "Microsoft.Azure.CreateUIDef",
  "version": "0.1.2-preview",
  "parameters": {
    "config": {
      "isWizard": true,
      "basics": {      
        "location": {
          "resourceTypes": [
            "microsoft.insights/components",
            "microsoft.insights/components/CurrentBillingFeatures", 
            "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
            "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
```

"microsoft.insights/components" is not available in West Central US currently and it was removed from the Location options.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
 {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/0.1.2-preview/CreateUIDefinition.MultiVm.json#",
        "handler": "Microsoft.Azure.CreateUIDef",
        "version": "0.1.2-preview",
        "parameters": {
            "config": {
                "isWizard": false,
                "basics": {
                    "location": {
                    "label": "Region",
                    "toolTip": "Choose the Azure region to deploy in. Only supported regions are listed.",
                    "resourceTypes": [
                        "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
                        ],
                    "allowedValues": [
                        "eastus",
                        "westus2"
                        ],
                    "visible": true
                    }
                }
            },
            "resourceTypes": [
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
                "Microsoft.Batch/batchAccounts"
            ],
            "basics": [
                {
                    "name": "resourceNamePrefix",
                    "type": "Microsoft.Common.TextBox",
                    "label": "Resource name prefix",
                    "defaultValue": "default",
                    "toolTip": "Specify a prefix...",
                    "visible": true,
                    "constraints": {
                        "regex": "...",
                        "validationMessage": "Must be...."
                    }
                }
            ],
            "steps": [
            ...
            ],
            "outputs": {
            ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I assume that I understand your question correctly. You want to deployment in a selected region.

Azure Resource Manager templates enable you to deploy and manage these resources as a group, using a JSON description of the resources and their deployment settings. When you create the template you can define the region of the resources with the "**location**" property. The code just like this:

```
{
      "condition": "<true-to-deploy-this-resource>",
      "apiVersion": "<api-version-of-resource>",
      "type": "<resource-provider-namespace/resource-type-name>",
      "name": "<name-of-the-resource>",
      "location": "<location-of-resource>",
      ...
}
```

If you want to create all the resources in the template in one selected region, you can set the "**location**" all with the same value. And then use the CLI command [`az group deployment create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/group/deployment?view=azure-cli-latest#az-group-deployment-create) or PowerShell command [`New-AzureRmDeployment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermdeployment?view=azurermps-6.11.0) to deploy the template to Azure.

Comment: this modification suggestion applies to mainTemplate.json. I am looking for to restrict the locations in createUidefinition.json itself.